# Cucumber: Use the exact same gherkin setup step in every feature file

Tags: cucumber

Imagine I have two different features:

- get.feature
- update.feature

I would not put those two features `get` and `update` into the same feature file because they do not belong together logically. But what I can do is: I can use the same data - the same gherkin setup step:

```
Given there are the following entries in the database
    | id | value |
    | 1  | bla   |
    | 2  | blub  |
```

The problem now is that I cannot create a `Background` for that since I will have two different features:

```
Feature: Get
    // Here I want to use the given step which will be the same for each feature
    When ...
    Then ...
```

```
Feature: Update
    // Here I want to use the given step which will be the same for each feature
    When ...
    Then ...
```

How can I setup my cucumber steps so that I can achieve the reusing of `given` gherkin steps in each feature?

Comment: You can reuse the steps/ step def in different features. Or if you like to run same setup before each scenario, you will have to use the @Before hooks.

Comment: @Mulgard, You can always reuse the Step Definitions in any feature files. And in your case the _Given_ step you can put in **Background**.

Comment: Hi! I do not want to reuse the step definitions. I want to reuse the gherkin step. I also can not use a background across multiple feature files.

Comment: @Mulgard, If you want to reuse gherkin step then the step definitions should be reused

Comment: I dont think that I understand what you mean. I have two independent features and I do not want to write my the data table in my `given` step more than one time. I want to use the same data table in each feature file. How should reusing the step definition help me with that? The step definition expects a data table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is just to call the step in each feature file. Now if this is tedious because your step is badly written step with a huge data table just re-write the step without the data table.

So with your example

```
Given there are the following entries in the database
    | id | value |
    | 1  | bla   |
    | 2  | blub  |
```

Change it too

```
Given bla and blub are in the database
```

By doing this you have pushed the HOW down from the feature to the step definition.

Lets say you implement this as something like

```
Given 'bla and blub are in the database' do
  db = get_connection
  ...
  db.insert(1, bla)
  db.insert(2, blub)
  ...
end
```

again you can push the HOW down by doing

```
Given 'bla and blub are in the database' do
  add_bla_and_blub_to_db
end
```

which is now using a helper method to do your implementation. And once you have helper methods you can call them from other step definitions.

TLDR make you steps simpler and just call the step in each feature.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use Hooks.  Within your stepdefinition package create a class (you don't have to call it hooks but you can) that includes a method with the @Before tag.  It will operate the same as background but will run across all of your feature files.  Make sure to import the one from Cucumber and not from JUnit.

```
public class Hooks {

  @Before
  public void doBefore(){
    //do things
  }
}
```

Comment: And How would I run the gherkin step from the @Before Hook? I need to get in the data table there.

Comment: You wouldn't.  You would instead create an array (of arrays most likely) in your hooks class that holds the information that your data table would.  If you HAVE to store the table in Gherkin, then you are going to have to write that table in all your feature files.

Comment: Ok. So I have to repeat myself in each feature file. Damn. Isnt that a huge weakpoint of cucumber?